# jQuery Selection Child of UL. Looking for a better method

Tags: jquery

I have a div element which contains UL and UL contains the LI items. One of the LI item has an ID of stocknumber. I need to select that li.

Here is my code which works fine I am just looking for a better implementation.

```
$(".block").children("ul").children("#stocknumber") // gets me the li and it works!!
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Please note that ids are not unique!

Here is what I came up with:

```
$(".block").children("ul").find("#stocknumber")
```

Comment: whatever you mean with "ids are not unique" you have to explain it before I remove the -1

Comment: ids HAVE to be unique. If not, your HTML is invalid

Comment: IDs on a web page must be unique, you will only cause yourself more trouble somewhere else using non-unique id attributes.

Comment: $(".block").find("#stocknumber", "ul"), similar to the above but instead of child/find, pass in a context to the find method.  If your looking to improve performance, you should use Firebug to analyze a few different selectors to find the best solution for your problem.

Comment: @jAndy You could have just asked the question before down grading it! Anyway, IDS are not unique since the DIV and everything is rendered inside the GridView control. But I am going to remove the id and use a class instead!

Comment: Well, I did ask. But putting a complete wrong thing into the question is a downvote to me

Comment: @johndoe: jAndy likes downvoting. Don't worry about it.

Comment: That is one mans opinion. I downvote anything which is just "wrong",if you have any problems with that you are on the wrong site.

Comment: @jAndy When you do not understand anything JUST ASK! That is what I do and it works good for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".block > ul > #stocknumber")
```

or even:

```
$("#stocknumber"); // because every id in your HTML should be unique
```

Comment: performance isn't always the most important thing. Simplicity is more important in most cases. Besides, the second one is the absolute fastest way of achieving what the OP wants

Comment: Indeed, the second method is better performing than any other combination of selectors would be.

Comment: you added the second line later, so its not.

Comment: But the first method is better than the others that use compound selectors, since it does not require full-depth searches underneath .block.

Comment: relaxe I wil remove it, but at the point I read it, it was worse than the original code from OP (still performance). nevermind

Comment: jAndy: as I mentioned in my first comment, in most cases performance of a selector is unimportant. Clean and maintainable code is a lot more important. If it wasn't, we'd all still be coding in C++

Comment: since javascript (better said DOM operations) are pretty damn slow, I would think about what you just said.

Comment: @jAndy: Philippe Leybaert's first example is far, far, far (30ms per run) quicker than the OP's original code.

Comment: Is this an organised voting war? @jAndy: you should read up on software architecture and performance literature. I know it is fun to squeeze the last bit of peformance out of a piece of code, but in most real-world scenarios it's usually not worth the trouble and even counter-productive in real production code.

Comment: Well I know about software architecture, but still, javascript and DOM operations I (maybe not you) always do prefer performance at (mostly) all costs.

Comment: @jAndy: How about we quit being so snappy over every comment and learn to accept that occasionally you're wrong? FWIW, I benchmarked `$('#method-list').children().find('h2.entry-title')` on http://api.jquery.com, but the results will be consistent on any markup you test it on.

Comment: With all due respect, the first method can be deceiving, because it implies that you are looking for the `#stocknumber` element that is under `.block > ul`, as opposed to the others (when there shouldn't be others). It may be a personal preference for you, but I think it could mislead future readers.

Comment: I agree with everyone that performance is not really a concern at this stage. Considering performance for this right now is thinking about removing a single corn flake from your bowl to consume exact calories. It will not make any difference!

Comment: @Matt: of course it is faster, but ONLY because the most right selector is an ID and sizzle works from right to left, so, I'm not snappy I'm right. In any other constelation his code will be slower.

Comment: @jAndy - I didn't know Sizzle worked right to left. That's interesting. I wonder if it is optimized such that it ignores anything to the left of an ID. Any idea?

Comment: That is the only explanation for Matts benchmark results, but I'm pretty sure sizzle will work exactly like that. Check the most right selecter, id? > just select it

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#stocknumber");
```

Since IDs are unique, you shouldn't have more than one element with the ID of `stocknumber` in your page.

Comment: In that case you should rethink your HTML markup.  IDs are required to be unique by the HTML spec :-) see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: john doe: You should do everything possible to keep ID's on a page unique.

Comment: Thanks @Matt! I think I will replace ID with class and that will do the trick as well. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely select it by its ID directly.

```
$('#stocknumber');
```

If you have more than one element with that same ID, it is bad, and you will have problems with your code.

In that situation, you should use classes instead of IDs, like this:

```
$(".block").find(".stocknumber");
```

or

```
$('.stocknumber', '.block');
```

With HTML like this:

```
<div class='block'>
    <ul>
        <li class='stocknumber'>number</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class='block'>
    <ul>
        <li class='stocknumber'>number</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just simplyfiying what OP did but you do have the point and yes i need to delete it. Thanks for notifying that.

Comment: @Sarfraz - OK, no offense. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#stocknumber')`.

Id's should be unique to the page. You're just slowing things down.

Comment: I might not be slowing things down since I get the DIV element from a function due to some drop operation. So, I only get the exact DIV element.

Answer (score 1):

If that LI has an id just do

```
$('#stocknumber')
```

since ids have to be unique in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got my answer using the find method.

```
$(".block").children("ul").find("#stocknumber")
```

Comment: `find()` is slower than `children()`. But take everyones criticism into consideration: You need to make these ID's unique. It brings unexpected behaviour. Look at using classes over ID's. Classes don't have to be unique.

Comment: find() is slower than children()? I really do not believe that.

Comment: @jAndy: `find()` searches all descendants. `children()` searches all children....